# SCP command line input issue

Tags: shell

I created a SCP script where it will take the source directory input from command line, but I see an issue with that, for example, If I want to copy 5 files under /var/lib directory then in my command line If I do /var/lib/* then each file is taken as a separate command line argument and my script fails, I can't even copy the whole lib directory because in destination I do not want that folder to be created. Any idea would help, thanks..!!

Comment: Please post your script

Comment: Instead of using */var/lib/** as a script parameter try to use just */var/lib/* but then add *-r* parameter to the *scp* command.